# Oracle Forms toolbar size

Tags: oracle, toolbar, oracleforms

When creating a menu in **Oracle Forms 6i**, you can set a property for each menu option to be visible or not in the horizontal menu toolbar. You can also set the icon for the button on the toolbar and the text to display when hovering your mouse over it.

What I cannot find is the properties for the toolbar itself. It doesn´t seem to be possible to change the size, color or any other property for the toolbar.

I specifically want to change the size of the icons, since being an old tool, it was designed by default to work with 16x16 icons, but with current screen resolutions, the toolbar looks way to small.

Using larger icons doesn´t do the trick, since it just cuts the icon to 16 by 16.

Am I missing something? is it possible to adjust the toolbars properties?

Comment: @APC heartbreaking. if you want to reply to the question instead of a comment I´ll give it an OK. do you have any source for this?

Comment: I presume you're still on 6i because you need client/server mode?

Comment: Nah, just inherited a BS application that I´m supposed to start maintaining... you wouldn't belive the kind of crap government will pay for.

Comment: I have no problems with Oracle, the problem is the development in 6i, bought in 2012 as an update for the previous system...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adjusting the size of the toolbar is a new feature in Forms 12c. It is not available in earlier versions.

> "do you have any source for this?"

I saw Michael Ferrante (the Forms Product Manager) talk at UKOUG on Monday. So straight from the horse's mouth :)  The Forms 12c New Features guide [is here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/forms/documentation/oracleforms-12210-newfeatures-2906037.pdf): page 12 is the page which will break your heart.